# Multiple RPOPLPUSH in redis

Tags: redis

I want to pop multiple items from list1 and want to push those popped elements in list 2.
Can anybody tell how it can be done in redis. The existing RPOPLPUSH list1 list2 does this but with only one element.

Answer (score 1):

Just use the `RPOPLPUSH` command in a loop, either in a native lua script or in your client application.  If you're worried about network lag issuing multiple commands, use a pipeline, or the server side script.

In general, the redis design philosophy is to give you pretty simple commands and let you build them up into more complex chains on the client side (A co-worker of mine described it as "Data assembly language"), rather than provide many narrow-use commands on the server side.  This way, they (read: Antirez) can focus on making the command set fast and reliable, rather than adding syntactic sugar.